# stack expects each tensor to be equal size pytorch

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm trying to train a cnn network for image classification. all the images are from the same size. But a mismatch error  of tensor size happned. Basically the error says some images are rotated.
The exact error message is here:

```
RuntimeError: stack expects each tensor to be equal size, but got [3, 200, 266] at entry 0 and [3, 266, 200] at entry 4
```

I wrote a simple program to check if any of the images are rotated using opencv.

```
for folder in folders:
    for f in glob(folder+"/*.jpg"):
        img = cv2.imread(f)
        if img.shape[1] != 200:
            print(f)
```

If there's a mismatch in size it should print the file name. But unfortunately nothing was printed means all the image are exactly the same size. Please Take note that I don't want to resize the image maybe can rotate it but not resize.

The code I use to read the data for training is below

```
train_transforms = transforms.Compose([
                                 transforms.ToTensor()])
    test_transforms = transforms.Compose([
                                      transforms.ToTensor()])
    train_data = datasets.ImageFolder(datadir,       
                    transform=train_transforms)
    test_data = datasets.ImageFolder(datadir,
                    transform=test_transforms)
    num_train = len(train_data)
    indices = list(range(num_train))
    split = int(np.floor(valid_size * num_train))
    np.random.shuffle(indices)
    from torch.utils.data.sampler import SubsetRandomSampler
    train_idx, test_idx = indices[split:], indices[:split]
    train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_idx)
    test_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(test_idx)
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data,
                   sampler=train_sampler, batch_size=5)
    testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_data,
                   sampler=test_sampler, batch_size=1)
```

Comment: Do you have Fully connected layer at the end ?

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer yes that's right I have fully connected layer at the end

Comment: You don't want to resize ?

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer No I don't want to resize the image coz I want to lose any information. If rotation it will fix the problem but if it's resize the ratios in the image will change

Comment: You can do padding to have all images of same shape otherwise you have to redesign your network to overcome this problem, if you want to have variable input shape. This would help : https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-create-convnet-for-variable-size-input-dimension-images/1906

Comment: @KnowledgeGainer This is not the problem. The issue is all my images are actually from the same size. But I don't know why the program gives this error. I have wrote a simple program to check if the images are the same size and it says all the images are exactly of the same shape